# is there a way to respond to a GET\POST outside of the specific (req, res) function?

Tags: node.js, express, request, response, low-level

using Express (NodeJS), is there a way to save the details of a request so that the response will be done in a later time? (basically, leaving the request hangin for the response). without using setTimeout() or sleep or any other delay.

for example if this is my function:

```
function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.json(data);
    }, 3000);
}
```

is it possible to use (req, res) objects outside that function scope AND succesfuly respond to a specific request on later time? (for example 30 seconds afterwards, or in a differenr part of the code)

Comment: not using setTimeout()

Comment: sounds like you are looking for long polling... Maybe a library like this? https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-delayed-response

Comment: When you say 'or in a different part of the code', do you mean at a different point of execution?  When you say 'later time', do you mean physical time or later on in the program?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think so.  The request/response are specific to the handler call.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  All you need to do is call a long-running non-async (blocking) function prior to calling `res.json()` or any other function that sends a response, e.g.

```
function(req, res) {
    var data = longRunningNonAsyncFsCall();
    res.jsonp(data);
}
```

I don't think `setTimeout()` is what you need.